# Expensive function inside useCallback hook called when no data change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the useCallback to memoize a callback that itself calls an expensive function, then sets the result as a state. In the example below, the goal is to run the query 'useDataQuery' and then use the callback function ONLY if the response data is different from the last time it was called. The page render relies on the contents of 'currentData'

```
const [currentData, currentDataSet] = useState({}) // Render based on 'currentData'

const dataQuery = useDataQuery(id, callbackMemo)

const callbackMemo = useCallback((data) => {
    const updatedData = expensiveFunction(data)
    currentDataSet(updatedData)
}, [dataQuery?.data])

const expensiveFunction = (data) => {
    console.log("Called expensive function")
    let updatedData;
    // Process the data inside this function to get result
    return updatedData;
}
```

However when I run, the console message prints on every visit indicating that the expensive function is still called even though the response from useDataQuery is the same. Is this possible?

EDIT: useDataQuery looks like this:

```
export const useDataQuery = (
  id: string,
  onSuccess?: Function
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [queryKeys.app.data],
    queryFn: async () =>
      await getData(
        queryKeys.app.data,
        id
      ),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      onSuccess && onSuccess(data);
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: What's the code like for `useDataQuery`?

Comment: @ClaireLin it's a React Query that makes an axios call, then onSuccess it calls the passed callback function (callbackMemo in my example), I've added it to the question for reference

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` memoizes based on reference equality. I Assume `useDataQuery` re-fetches data from server thus creates new instances every time. If the `expensiveFunction` is really expensive you could use the approach described here: https://usehooks.com/useMemoCompare/

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks